# AWS s3 functions work on local but not on AWS server

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am working on a project where users can upload objects in their own directory in server and this is my approach that works on localhost to create user directories:

```
$s3Client = new Aws\S3\S3Client([
               'version' => 'latest',
                'region' => 'ca-central-1'
]);

$s3Client->registerStreamWrapper();
$s3Dir = 's3://' . $bucketName . '/' . $folderName;
file_put_contents($s3Dir, '');
```

Since the code is working on local, I think it's not the problem of s3 permissions or bucket policies. My guess is php setting on AWS server is causing the issue. 
Any help would be great!

Comment: maybe you have your credentials set only on your localhost and not on the server? I would try first to connect on the server and try manually from there

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I granted S3 read write permission to user group and included confidential in formation to the environment variable on Elastic Beanstalk, but it's still not doing anything.